# BeautifulSoup search for an element returns [ ]

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

The page I am trying to work with is https://www.google.ca/flights/#search;f=YYC;t=CMH;d=2016-05-07;r=2016-05-11;tt=o  (or really any other flight search).  The "inspect element" option tells me the price associated with the lowest fare has the html `<div class="MHNSJI-d-zb">$260</div>`

I am trying to find the correct way to identify this element in BeautifulSoup so I can put the lowest fare into my variable lowFare.  I have read the bs4 docs and expected either

```
lowFare = soup.find_all('.MHNSJI-d-zb')
```

or

```
lowFare = soup.select('.MHNSJI-d-zb')
```

to give me the lowest available flight fare on a given flight search, but those just return `lowFare = []`.

I'm a beginner, so I know this is just a case of me doing it wrong, but after reading all the documentation I'm still lost.

Am I on the right track?  I found another question on this site that said the html might be hidden behind some javascript in the page, but I'm too new to know what to do with that, or if it even applies in my situation.

Thanks.

Comment: Rather than trying to scrape the fare from the Web page (which is hard because, indeed, the data isn't in the HTML) you should use the [QPX Express API](https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/). Unfortunately you will have to pay for more than 50 queries a day.

Comment: Inspect element shows the DOM after its been modified by javascript, how did you load the page's source in python?